# Git merging - What happens to the merged branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I have a question regarding git merging. Let's say I have two branches in my repository (both local and remotely): master and test. And while I was working on the test branch, the master branch got updated by some else. In the terminal, I write:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

And this updates my master branch with the recently added stuff right? Then, I finish what I was doing in my test branch.
If I go to the terminal and write:

```
git checkout master
git merge test
git push origin master
```

This merges my test branch into my master branch and then pushes the changes to github right (let's assume there are no conflicts)? My question is: what happens to the test branch? Does it stay the same way it was before the merge? Or do both the test and the master branch become the same? Should I do this now to update the test branch?

```
git checkout test
git pull origin master
git push origin test
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it stays the same, unless you merge back master into test
`git checkout test` `git merge master`...

Comment: @n00dl3 If I have conflicts when merging test into master, will I also have conflicts when merging the new master into test?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If I go to the terminal and write:
>
> ```
> git checkout master
> git merge test
> git push origin master
> ```
>
> This merges my test branch into my master branch and then pushes the changes to github right (let's assume there are no conflicts)? My question is: what happens to the test branch?

Nothing at all.

Remember that branch *names* are simply names for a (single) commit.  To draw them, I like to draw the commits themselves as round `o` nodes, or uppercase single letters when we need to talk about specific commits, with lines connecting them:

```
...--o--o--o--o      <-- master
         \       
          o--o--o    <-- test
```

Each commit "points back" to its parent commit—so if we give each of these commits a letter name, and draw in all the intermediate arrows, we get:

```
...<-A<-B<-C<-D      <-- master
         \
          E<-F<-G    <-- test
```

The branch names, `master` and `test`, actually contain the raw hash IDs of the tips of the two branches.  That is, if you examine the file `.git/refs/heads/master`<sup>1</sup> you'll find one of those big ugly 40-character hashes, `a139fc7...` or whatever, inside it.

In effect, `master` points to commit `D`, and `test` points to `G`.  Commit `D` points back to commit `C`, which points back to `B`, and so on; and commit `G` points back to `F`, which points back to `E`, which points back to `B` (it's too tricky to draw an arrow with plain text here, since some good arrow-drawing fonts only work on some machines).

When you're on some branch and make a *new* commit, the way Git makes this commit is that it writes the new commit with its parent set to the current branch-tip, and then once the new commit is safely in the repository, rewrites the branch *name* file with the new commit's ID.  This makes the branch name point to the new tip.  The new ID goes nowhere else, so no *other* branch names change in any way.

A merge commit has *two* parents, so when you `git merge test` and it works, you get this:

```
...--o--o--o--o---o  <-- master
         \       /
          o--o--o    <-- test
```

Note that `test` has not moved at all, but `master` has—and the new merge commit points back to two different earlier commits: the old branch-tip of `master`, and the (unchanged) tip of `test`.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's no promise that this file will exist in the future, or stay in this location or have this format, but right now, with today's Git versions through 2.10, you will generally have that file.

Comment: So what would be the best approach in this case? Delete the branch test, and then create a new one? Or pull the master changes into test as well?

Comment: That depends on what *you* want to do (or keep doing, or not do anymore) with `test`.  If your `test` name is not on the remote (if you never push it and do not get it from there in the first place, so that there is no `origin/test` that you use to co-ordinate with other people), the decision is entirely yours. Otherwise, negotiate with the other users of it to figure out what you all would prefer.

Comment: @torek So, assuming test branch is local (never got pushed), after the merge, when you push the changes, the test branch gets pushed as well in order to maintain the reference of the 2 parent nodes? What happens if I delete it then?

Comment: @JohnnyBeltran: First, remember that you don't push *changes*, you push *commits*. When you run `git push` or `git push <remote-or-URL>`, your Git calls up some other Git. You (well, your git) and they (their Git) have some set of commits. You may have *new* (to them anyway) commits: you have your Git hand over some new commits if needed. Then you ask their Git to set one or more of *their* names—usually branch names—to remember some particular commits, usually ones you have just sent them.

Comment: So, if you send over your new merge commit, you can then just ask them to set *their* branch `test`, or `master`, or whatever, to remember this new commit. The new commit you just sent them is a merge commit, so that commit itself remembers both of *its* parents, which each remember their parents, and so on.

Comment: If you have your Git ask them to set their name `test`, and they don't have a branch named `test` yet, they will normally create that name at that time. If they do have that name, they will verify that this request—to set their name `test` to remember this merge commit—is a *fast forward* operation. If it is, they will allow this request. If not, they will send back an error and you'll see `! rejected  (non-fast-forward)`.

Comment: @torek But I'd have to explicitly ask their git to set their name test, right? I made a repo to understand better. I cloned the repo twice in two separate directories. In one directory I created "file1", committed it and pushed it. In the other repo, I created a branch (git checkout -b test), created "file2", added it and committed it. Then, I switched to master and pulled. After that I did `git merge test` and another commit was made. Then, I pushed these commits. Now, when I use `git log --graph` I can see the branch made after the initial commit.

Comment: @JohnnyBeltran: `git push <where> <what>` *always* asks them to set a name. The name comes from the `<what>` part; in modern Git, the default "what", if you leave it out, is your current branch name. Note that you don't have to use the same name on both sides, though: `git push origin ourbranch:theirname` asks them to set the name `theirname` to correspond to the commit that is the tip of branch `ourbranch` in the local Git repository.

Comment: However, github does not seem to know about a branch other than master (I only see a straight line at the side), but when I click the merge commit I can see the 2 parents. [Demo repo here](https://github.com/jfbeltran97/merge-push-demo)

Comment: Again, if you leave the name out, the default is the *current branch*. So, if you run `git checkout master; git merge test; git push` you are now running `git push origin master` because your *current branch* is `master`. So you're asking `origin` to set their `master` the same as your `master`. Your `master` identifies the merge commit you just made, so this creates-or-updates their `master`, assuming they don't reject your request anyway.

Comment: The key here is that it is the *commits* that matter. The *names* just help a Git repository (and a human using that repository) *find* the commit(s). Each Git repository has its own names; the commits, on the other hand, have the same hash ID in *every* Git repository.

Comment: "So you're asking origin to set their master the same as your master" got it. "The key here is that it is the commits that matter", I definitely get that now. So, after the merge, all the commits are actually part of the master branch (despite the visual branching). Now, this is a problem when trying to go back to a commit before the merge, because you can only do so choosing one of the parents (which are just commits) and that's why it is recommended to use rebase, to "make everything a straight line". Is that right?

Comment: @JohnnyBeltran: Well, *some* recommend that sort of rebase straight-line trick. Others swear by using and keeping merges at all times. I am of the opinion that one should use whatever works best for you and your group. :-)